# PHP error dump message are truncated to 5 characters only

Tags: php, apache, runtime-error, wamp

**PROBLEM**: Error dump messages are truncated to 5 characters only.
In the following example it is 'Canno'

```
[07-Nov-2022 23:42:06 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Canno in /httpdocs/includes/Database.php on line 570
[07-Nov-2022 23:42:06 Europe/Berlin] PHP Stack trace:
[07-Nov-2022 23:42:06 Europe/Berlin] PHP   1. {main}() /httpdocs/home.php:0
[07-Nov-2022 23:42:06 Europe/Berlin] PHP   2. require_once() /httpdocs/home.php:4
[07-Nov-2022 23:42:06 Europe/Berlin] PHP   3. require_once() /httpdocs/includes/master.inc.php:61
```

P.S. the question is NOT about the PHP error, but about the SIZE of the error message itself. In some cases it is 3 chars only in others - 5.
No more, no less.

Yes, it happened on

- client's server
- local machine, Apache, php 5.6.

Yes, I immediately checked the php.ini settings for log-errors-max-len  or any other trace of incnsistency, but found no problems at all.

Comment: Well start by showing us `Database.php` with code around line 570

Comment: yo could also try turning error reporting on so you get errors to the page, just while you debug

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Thank you, Captain! I'm NOT talking about debugging issue but about dump into the error log.
Like about 2 hrs: [10-Nov-2022 15:03:44 Asia/Tel_Aviv] PHP Fatal error:  Cal in Unknown on line 0

Comment: This is NOT usual. I can only think you have done something very odd to something (no idea what) in the config of PHP maybe

Comment: @RiggsFolly You're addressing the error itself but NOT the question asked. 
MY QUESTION WAS (and still is): Why the heck error messages are truncated to 3-5 characters only! It is solely server configuration issue, but I never experienced this shit.

Comment: Its easy to toss words like that around when you find you are out of your depth. WAMPServer is just Apache, MySQL, PHP nothing more or less

Comment: So did you check the setting of [log-errors-max-len](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors-max-len) in the `php.ini` file. Maybe the previous developer did some odd fiddling

Comment: As I said in my previous comment "Thank You Captain! @RiggsFolly
FIRST - EXACTLY the same behavior is as the client's web server. SECOND, surely, when I saw the size of the error messages in the error log, I checked the  log-errors-max-len line. It was 1024 on the server and 3072 (which was changed from 0) on the WAMP. So this behavior is SOMEHOW consistent.... while I have no direct access to the server's PHP.ini (in the end - PHP is responible for PHP errors :))

Comment: _surely, when I saw the size of the error messages in the error log, I checked the log-errors-max-len line_ Then tell us that in the question OR expect to have it suggesed

Answer (score 2):

An idiot programmer put a ini_set("log_errors_max_len", 3); message in one of major include files....somewhere in the middle of the file....and ini_set("log_errors_max_len", 5); in another.

I found it, when explicitly started to eliminate gazillion of includes. And in some cases received 3char messages , while some others gave 5 chars.